# Archive for qualifying exams for advanced calculus.

Tags: calculus

Does anyone have an archive of masters level archive questions for advanced calculus? I was able to find qualifying and preliminary exam archives for linear algebra and complex analysis. But I nothing for advanced calculus (not real analysis)

Sorry for not being clear earlier: What books would you recommend which cover the following areas:

Real numbers. Functions of one variable: continuity, mean-value theorems, convergence, differentiability, maxima and minima, integrals, fundamental theorem of calculus, inequalities, estimation of sums and integrals, elementary functions and their power series. Functions of several variables: partial derivatives, chain rule, MacLaurin expansion, critical points, Lagrange multipliers, inverse and implicit function theorems, Jacobian, divergence and curl, area and volume integrals, Green and Stokes theorems.

Comment: what is advanced calculus ? to you have the list of the theorems, definitions, the chapters of your course ?

Comment: @cauchyprobability: I think you are going to have google them and find things like: http://www.artsci.uc.edu/departments/math/grad/PhD_Preliminary_Exams_Semesters/adv_calc_and_lin_alg.html, http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/aim-grad/PhD/Requirements/AIM-QR-Exams/

Comment: @user1952009 Let me post the syllabus here: Real numbers. Functions of one variable: continuity, mean-value theorems, convergence, differentiability, maxima and minima, integrals, fundamental theorem of calculus, inequalities, estimation of sums and integrals, elementary functions and their power series. Functions of several variables: partial derivatives, chain rule, MacLaurin expansion, critical points, Lagrange multipliers, inverse and implicit function theorems, Jacobian, divergence and curl, area and volume integrals, Green and Stokes theorems.